# %n not working in printf

Tags: c

I have a problem, %n in printf doesn't work, i'm using Dev-Cpp 5.3.0.4 on win7

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int n;
char *x;
gets(x);
printf("\n%s%n\n",x,&n);
printf("n: %d\n",n);
return 0;
}
```

output:

```
hello how are you?

hello how are you?n: 2046

--------------------------------
Process exited with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

why? how can i solve? thanks in advance ;)

Comment: You haven't initialized `x`...

Comment: Uh, you just changed `n` to `&n` in your code... so did you actually try it with `&n` and just post the wrong question?

Comment: @thejh i've posted wrong question, code is right with &n but it's still not working

Comment: @ArtemGlukhov `x` is an uninitialized pointer. Initialize it with something like: `x=malloc(256);` Or change it to `char x[256];` or whatever size.

Comment: @KingsIndian tried with 'x=malloc(256);' and 'char x[256];'.. but still nothing! when it write me n, it write casual big number

Comment: @KingsIndian just rebooted and still nothing :( tried with your code and still nothing!!!

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the `printf` manpage:

> ```
>    n      The  number of characters written so far is stored into the integer indicated by the int
>           * (or variant) pointer argument.  No argument is converted.
> ```

So, you'll have to pass a *pointer to* an int. Also, as Xavier Holt pointed out, you'll have to use a valid buffer to read into. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int n;
  char x[1000];
  fgets(x, 1000, stdin);
  printf("\n%s%n\n",x,&n);
  printf("n: %d\n",n);
  return 0;
}
```

This code works for me.

Comment: +1  But there's another bug in OP's code that'll keep that from working: `x` needs to point to a valid buffer to read into.  Otherwise...  Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer to `n`.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `n` needs to be a pointer to a signed int, not a singed int.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how to use the "%n" specifier.

See [the C99 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.1).

> n
>      The argument shall be a pointer to signed integer into which is written the number of characters written to the output stream so far by this call to fprintf. No argument is converted, but one is consumed. If the conversion specification includes any flags, a field width, or a precision, the behavior is undefined.

Also you need some place to store the input (hint: initialize `x`)